# Can $x$ be written as a $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$-algebraic combination of $x+xy$, $y+xy$, $x^2$, and $y^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I was wondering how to write $x$ as an algebraic combination of $\{x+xy,y+xy,x^2,y^2\}$, with the coefficients $\in \mathbb Q[x,y]$.

Comment: I think that the kind of combination that you want is called an _algebraic_ combination.

Comment: I've revised my answer to include a solution to this new, edited problem. See my post below.

Comment: @alex.jordan Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

**New problem**: Take $(x+xy)-x(y+xy)+y(x^2)$. This simplifies to $x+xy-xy-x^2y+x^2y=x$.

**Old problem**: This is not possible. To see why, examine $x= a(x+xy)+b(y+xy)+cx^2+dy^2$ with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}$. We then have that $x= ax+by+(a+b)xy+cx^2+dy^2$. Equating coefficients, we see that $b$ must be 0 and $a$ must be 1. But then the coefficient of $xy$ is 1 on the RHS and 0 on the LHS, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot.